Flask session stores datetime object without timezone with timezone
So I'm trying to understand why Flask session store objects in different datatype that innitially configured with.
I have something like below
from flask import Flask, session, redirect, url_for, render_template
from datetime import datetime

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'your_secret_key'

@app.route('/set_date')
def set_date():
    date_str = "07-01-2024"
    date = datetime.strptime(date_str, "%m-%d-%Y")
    print(date.dtype)
    session['date'] = date.strftime("%m-%d-%Y")
    return redirect(url_for('get_date'))

@app.route('/get_date')
def get_date():
    date = session.get('date')
    print(date.dtype)
    return render_template("index.html")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)

The initial date prior to being stored in the session was a datetime.datetime(2024, 7, 1, 0, 0) yet when retrived from session it became a datetime.datetime(2024, 7, 1, 0, 0, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc). why was timezone added? Is this normal behaviour?
